# React Native Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got this error, and I want help

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from D:\\gp\\assets\\1-system-iconshome.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
\> 1 |  PNG
  2 | →
  3 |
  4 | IHDRH♠U  G        pHYs!8!8☺E 1\`☺sRGB  ∟ ♦gAMA  
 a♣♦ IDATx☺ 1S‼A¶  ^ q  N  ☺∟ql  0c/tv& F    
  j u ☻◄   ☻\>C RȀ ↔   FF↕r {I↑Ir  \\    ◄ {    w  ▲  \`0↑
 §♠C   p ؠCl   \_▬ \]  Ώ   "6$ ^ x§ ♣  !Fb§  6邻   T XP \\         
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ModuleResolution.js:153:15)    
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph.js:279:43)
    at D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\lib\\transformHelpers.js:176:21
    at resolveDependencies (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:56:25)
    at visit (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:107:30)
    at async Promise.all (index 6)
    at async visit (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:116:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 9)
    at async visit (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:116:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from D:\\gp\\assets\\profile.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:    
  node_modules
\> 1 |  PNG
  2 | →
  3 |
  4 | IHDR(♠   m        pHYs
‼
‼☺  ↑☺sRGB  ∟ ♦gAMA  
 a♣
hIDATx☺ X o∟ ↔      ^\_ ‼\_ ↑۱E‼oMBBU . B  @(  @ 
U    § 8OU V  H R T  p( ►(vp 7_H  ^{  ݝ s ;gv b/  s2 g   w?→  →   c►   \_ Ǆ►1   ↓
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ModuleResolution.js:153:15)    
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph.js:279:43)
    at D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\lib\\transformHelpers.js:176:21
    at resolveDependencies (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:56:25)
    at visit (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:107:30)
    at async Promise.all (index 5)
    at async visit (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:116:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at async visit (D:\\gp\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\buildSubgraph.js:116:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
```

This is my source code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, View, Text, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import FormSection from "../components/FormSection";
import ProfileForm from "../components/ProfileForm";
import { FontFamily, FontSize, Color, Border, Padding } from "../GlobalStyles";



const AndroidLarge1 = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={[styles.androidLarge1, styles.androidLarge1Layout]}>
      <View style={[styles.frameParent, styles.text2Position]}>
        <View style={[styles.frameGroup, styles.groupFlexBox]}>
          <View style={styles.avatarParent}>
            <View style={styles.avatar}>
              <Image
                style={[
                  styles.circle40invisibleIcon,
                  styles.androidLarge1Layout,
                ]}
                resizeMode="cover"
                source={require("../assets/profile.png")} 
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.parent}>
              <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textTypo]}>Hello</Text>
              <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textTypo]}>Farmer</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.systemIconssettingParent}>
            <Image
              style={styles.systemLayout}
              resizeMode="cover"
              source={require("../assets/iconssetting.png")} 
            />
            <Image
              style={[styles.systemIconsnotification, styles.systemLayout]}
              resizeMode="cover"
              source={require("../assets/iconsnotification.png")} 
            />
          </View>
        </View>
        {/* ... (your existing code) */}
      </View>
      <ProfileForm showHomeIndicator={false} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to downgrade the React native version and the gradle version I use the RN version
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.1",
then I use
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-native": "0.72.8",
It works for Me you need to match some dependencies related to the version of react native